# Google Play App Integrity API works for full app but not instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to add instant app support to my existing app.  My app has app integrity enabled and it passes when I run the full app locally.  When I run the instant app locally however it fails.  Are there additional steps that I need to undertake to get the Google Play app integrity API to work with an android instant app? The error I'm receiving is below:

```
HTTP Client: RESPONSE: 200 
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
FROM: https://mobile.test.com/attest/initiate
COMMON HEADERS
-> Connection: keep-alive
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2024 17:33:04 GMT
-> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
BODY Content-Type: application/json
BODY START
{"id":"1e08f389-3fb1-41f9-89de-73a30f22627a","challenge":"080d7584-cc65-4882-9373-48f2094ff873"}
BODY END
INTEGRITY_API - key is null, getting token
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=080d7584-cc65-4882-9373-48f2094ff873, cloudProjectNumber=null, network=null})
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
UID: [11277]  PID: [998] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
INTEGRITY_API - token fetched = eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.aiK93UfZDzqAyHqq0uYE0zQnYBLFCSQKLMKwBjqWdKYJxwa4evfPOg.L5XG_-SLX9K-iSJR.Wx4eHtrFS7i_8LCUOSS2stgIlMh8cYODviwWc6MPdJ8DpucONA5fcjf7P1ZM7_xZgji8Y1UIRUnx7YzGxNbxgVVOg1drQkJwcu7Qkv3EcfvTQ7I7Ih7sFSJ8LFIFqRKJ-_iCCcBW3VzcWYhAXFgG9nJCIqnkaz6ZNdAb5boq8YykRyBQnJGo1QZAqEHaCss8hBGVMCYvZGd5IyKrnQodMKpTlDnTO5Ge_pn5pW2ys4-JmkMSVpcP5ZGVg0EO93RVv1Ztzco_LRhdB5aVhRDShpmImPmEubK7BJInOpVRgxCQHwQdTfWh_EQes9WW-gCGzzYNPOPyCmBEeoPDPoo649T9Dz-Was0BZA6L6iIiUYSVH6_U_HkTDVSStdH923YRwKZ-L4MhwE2PJ8F3tsgohAmX8xoqc_vZ490sgyby63O2s08aBhqxW7QJGmaz-mGL5aUvhxIsu_Ws_LigIvlYPMykM0cukNBRz8XD19R9oTGUE2fjM_Ydo1VNZPmk4vAFc3_gDxrPlczRtd165l7mYrYhH8J-uT8kAzVrZtqChEm2QryUd98137mTVPjANKu0Ycx3aCVRwV5-xj5ye0f1DREafZtOHAfVlhiViTx3FMlsCDF-flbwlRcOEF2DivHAx870l70w9gV9Sro-QUVsmQV_NhDaXnUELTs4Og9EKoyuIJ-G0xPY2MOMT_x2_nSu79FjQIb2NFa-SSt4BjvQShVv_69LV8cq8Wi17N6_EKuuzNTZsz3sBQ_SBRIbZfI4lSWpyLlYekolyuUTN_YA4JDalg0f-ukt9_xGcAnY0rp6xcx9C-LCXPkHnGkodziAO3KPos0Uqd9MrlD4rn_m3vMg5X1Om_CdEaIH9_ECWCmRsQTcVlnklZwRaRjfHszEflKPPH41ajMoVpvwFYtZf2yVmDParsx5PBHS7sCNxKPEEb4JyUAnezIywoBwJahkKCK8GO9SWtqlicMFduFFZ1Pm0P2wotU73Qflw8b07N3lgf0IF8onzlU-AQYQpOKVwBh1vQWDyAEgqXJax7SeHQ5qtTovYYLgKhgpYq_6pHK3dLHr3N4FlV4jFjej6jirkua2Tla2Wj8w7inr3WLQsvtINC2vPsQ.rTOdQ1UXOGfj0-ObclpgIQ
HTTP Client: REQUEST: https://mobile.test.com/attest/validate/android
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
COMMON HEADERS
-> Accept: application/json
-> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
CONTENT HEADERS
-> Content-Length: 1365
-> Content-Type: application/json
BODY Content-Type: application/json
BODY START
{
    "id": "1e08f389-3fb1-41f9-89de-73a30f22627a",
    "deviceId": "54416d35432dba1d",
    "verdict": "eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.aiK93UfZDzqAyHqq0uYE0zQnYBLFCSQKLMKwBjqWdKYJxwa4evfPOg.L5XG_-SLX9K-iSJR.Wx4eHtrFS7i_8LCUOSS2stgIlMh8cYODviwWc6MPdJ8DpucONA5fcjf7P1ZM7_xZgji8Y1UIRUnx7YzGxNbxgVVOg1drQkJwcu7Qkv3EcfvTQ7I7Ih7sFSJ8LFIFqRKJ-_iCCcBW3VzcWYhAXFgG9nJCIqnkaz6ZNdAb5boq8YykRyBQnJGo1QZAqEHaCss8hBGVMCYvZGd5IyKrnQodMKpTlDnTO5Ge_pn5pW2ys4-JmkMSVpcP5ZGVg0EO93RVv1Ztzco_LRhdB5aVhRDShpmImPmEubK7BJInOpVRgxCQHwQdTfWh_EQes9WW-gCGzzYNPOPyCmBEeoPDPoo649T9Dz-Was0BZA6L6iIiUYSVH6_U_HkTDVSStdH923YRwKZ-L4MhwE2PJ8F3tsgohAmX8xoqc_vZ490sgyby63O2s08aBhqxW7QJGmaz-mGL5aUvhxIsu_Ws_LigIvlYPMykM0cukNBRz8XD19R9oTGUE2fjM_Ydo1VNZPmk4vAFc3_gDxrPlczRtd165l7mYrYhH8J-uT8kAzVrZtqChEm2QryUd98137mTVPjANKu0Ycx3aCVRwV5-xj5ye0f1DREafZtOHAfVlhiViTx3FMlsCDF-flbwlRcOEF2DivHAx870l70w9gV9Sro-QUVsmQV_NhDaXnUELTs4Og9EKoyuIJ-G0xPY2MOMT_x2_nSu79FjQIb2NFa-SSt4BjvQShVv_69LV8cq8Wi17N6_EKuuzNTZsz3sBQ_SBRIbZfI4lSWpyLlYekolyuUTN_YA4JDalg0f-ukt9_xGcAnY0rp6xcx9C-LCXPkHnGkodziAO3KPos0Uqd9MrlD4rn_m3vMg5X1Om_CdEaIH9_ECWCmRsQTcVlnklZwRaRjfHszEflKPPH41ajMoVpvwFYtZf2yVmDParsx5PBHS7sCNxKPEEb4JyUAnezIywoBwJahkKCK8GO9SWtqlicMFduFFZ1Pm0P2wotU73Qflw8b07N3lgf0IF8onzlU-AQYQpOKVwBh1vQWDyAEgqXJax7SeHQ5qtTovYYLgKhgpYq_6pHK3dLHr3N4FlV4jFjej6jirkua2Tla2Wj8w7inr3WLQsvtINC2vPsQ.rTOdQ1UXOGfj0-ObclpgIQ"
}
BODY END
tagSocket(129) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
HTTP Client: RESPONSE: 403 
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
FROM: https://mobile.test.com/attest/validate/android
COMMON HEADERS
-> Connection: keep-alive
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2024 17:33:06 GMT
-> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
BODY Content-Type: application/json
BODY START
{"message":"Validation failed app"}
BODY END
INTEGRITY_API - onFailure = io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST https://mobile.test.com/attest/validate/android) invalid: 403 . Text: "{"message":"Validation failed app"}"
Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length: param, result, 133
HTTP Client: REQUEST: https://api.cove.test.com/logs/VENDORID/54416d35432dba1d
METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
COMMON HEADERS
-> Accept: application/json
-> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
CONTENT HEADERS
-> Content-Length: 292
-> Content-Type: application/json
BODY Content-Type: application/json
BODY START
{
    "log": "result=Client request(POST https://mobile.test.com/attest/validate/android) invalid: 403 . Text: \"{\"message\":\"Validation failed app\"}\"\ncove_error_type=app_attestation\nversion=2.0.1.77\nbuild=77\ndevice=oriole\nos=34\nvendor_id=54416d35432dba1d\nenvironment=prod"
}
BODY END
```

Comment: Hello James! What is an actual error you are getting? Can you share the logcat?

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant section of logcat.

Comment: From the updated logs it looks like the token was fetched and everything works so I suppose these are the logs for the successful scenario? Do you get API_NOT_AVAILABLE for the failed scenario? As I checked and unfortunately PIA is not available for the instant apps. I would recommend to submit the feature request from the Pay Console->App Integrity->Settings-> Get Support. Thank you!

Comment: The logs are from the failed scenario.  The very last message is "Validation failed app", so the token was retrieved, but it had a failing verdict.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad! It is enabled for the instant apps now! Could you, please, re-run the PIA in the instant app and send me more recent logs?

Comment: I've attached logs from this morning.

Comment: Sorry but I'd need the "challenge"/"nonce" you are sending to identify the request on our side. Could you, please, send me this?

Comment: I've updated the logs to include the challenge and nonce.

Comment: It looks like this app version is unknown to google play: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdicts#application-integrity-field
UNRECOGNIZED_VERSION
The certificate or package name does not match Google Play records.
Could you publish the instant app version for internal testing track and then check if you still see "UNRECOGNIZED"?

Comment: I  still see "UNRECOGNIZED" after publishing to Google Play.

Comment: I still see that for instant apps release the last published version is 37 while the request with the failing app attestation is for version 77.. could you, please, publish the app in the internal release for the instant apps track?